# Unable to call save method of filerefence class in script tag of flex 3 application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am trying to call method save of filerefence call in script of flex 3 application but application doesnot show the option  of save method.

Please answer this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click on Project and click on properties

then goto Flex Compiler
in HTML Wrapper

Change the required Flash Player version to 10.0.0

[image]

Comment: if your browser doesn't support flash version 10.0.0 then install that or run that application in Google Chrome Browser.

Please accept the answer if answer is satisfied...

Answer (score 0):

FileReference.save() is only available for Flash player 10 and above. If your flex sdk is running with Flash 9.0 you wouldn't be able to use it. Either move to latest SDK version or implement it using different way wiothout using the save()  method.